# Найти сумму, используя регулярные выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

Народ, помогите разобраться. Нужно использовать регулярные выражения. Обычным способом решил, а что-то через регулярные выражения не до конца разобрался.

Файл `in.properties` (состоящий из пар ключ=значение) содержит несколько строк. Пусть элемент с ключом `indexi` имеет значение `j (i=1..n, j=1..m` - натуральные числа без ведущих нулей). Значение `j` соответствует индексу элемента `valueij`, именно эти элементы нас интересуют.

Найти сумму значений элементов valueij. Найти кол-во индексирующих элементов с ошибками данных.

И вывести на экран:

```
sum = 8.24
error-lines = 3
```

К примеру, файл:

```
index1 = 3
value11=qw
value12=4
value13 = 5.1    
value14=2.7
index2=15
value21=
value22=
value23=
value24=k
value25=5
index3=1
value31=     3.14
value32=fgh
value33=5
index4=0
value41=
value42=e1
value43=2
value44=3
index5=b
value51=d
value52=e
```

Т.е. берем `index1`, его значение равно 3. Значит, ищем элемент `value13` и добавляем его значение к сумме. Потом `index2`, значение равно 15. Элемент `value215` не существует, увеличиваем счетчик ошибок. У `index3` значение 1, значит `value31` плюсуем в сумму. У `index4` значение равно 0, а у `index5` и вовсе 'a', следовательно они оба идут в ошибки.

Итого выходит:

```
сумма = 5.1 + 3.15 = 8.24
ошибки = 3
```

Для чтения из файла я использовал:

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("in");
Enumeration<String> keys = rb.getKeys();
String key;
while(keys.hasMoreElements()) {
 key = keys.nextElement();
 ...
}
```

А вот как дальше? Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Comment: Задача выглядит довольно бредово. Ну так добавьте все значения в мапу и обработайте их по порядку.

Answer (score 2):

Вот регулярное выражение которое ищет valueXY = Z для indexX = Y
Ошибкой считается:
 1. Если X - не целое число
 2. Если Y - не целое число
 3. Если valueXY - не существует
 4. Если Z - не рациональное число

```
re =/
  ^index(?:([\d]+) *\= *([\d]+) *|.*)$
  (?:
    (?:
      (?:\n.*$)*?
      (?:\nvalue\1\2 *= *([\d\.\-]+) *$)
      (?:\n.*$)*?
    )|
    (?:\n.*$)*?
  )
  (?:(?!\n)|(?=\nindex))
/gm
```

Вот программа, с тестовым заданием ( JavaScript )

```
str = [];

str.push("index1 = 3");
str.push("value11=qw");
str.push("value12=4");
str.push("value13 = 5.1    ");
str.push("value14=2.7");
str.push("index2=15");
str.push("value21=");
str.push("value22=");
str.push("value23=");
str.push("value24=k");
str.push("value25=5");
str.push("index3=1");
str.push("value31=     3.14");
str.push("value32=fgh");
str.push("value33=5");
str.push("index4=0");
str.push("value41=");
str.push("value42=e1");
str.push("value43=2");
str.push("value44=3");
str.push("index5=b");
str.push("value51=d");
str.push("value52=e");

str = str.join("\n");

function calc(str){
  var re =/^index(?:([\d]+) *\= *([\d]+) *|.*)$(?:(?:(?:\n.*$)*?(?:\nvalue\1\2 *= *([\d\.]+) *$)(?:\n.*$)*?)|(?:\n.*$)*?)(?:(?!\n)|(?=\nindex))/gm;

  var sum = 0,
      err = 0,
      res;

  while( res = re.exec(str) ){
    if ( res[3] ) sum += parseFloat( res[3] );
    else err++;
  }

  alert( 'Sum:' + sum + '\nError:' + err);
}

calc(str);
```

P.S: Без консоли - можно запустить через адресную строку браузера: пишем **javascript:**, после вставляем код, и жмем Enter

Comment: Это конечно здорово ! 

Но, я никогда бы не решился применить нечто подобное (такое сложное регулярное выражение) в **реальной** программе. 

Думаю, что уже через месяц даже автор не сможет вспомнить (если программу надо будет изменить) что там и зачем.

А потом, если во входных данных ошибка (не число), как ее локализовать ?

Поэтому  PHP и Perl языки крайне опасные для мало-мальски больших проектов.

Comment: Если сохранять regexp в том виде, как в первом блоке кода, да ещё с добавленными комментариями - то сложности с поддержкой не будет)<br>
Добавить ещё одно условие)